# Can i bind against a DynamicObject in WinRT / Windows 8 Store Apps

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have the following code:

```
    public class MyClass: DynamicObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (properties.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = properties[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Invalid Property!";
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        properties[binder.Name] = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(binder.Name);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        dynamic method = properties[binder.Name];
        result = method(args[0].ToString(), args[1].ToString());
        return true;
    }

    ///.... Rest of the class.
    }
```

When i bind against it from xaml, debug points in TryGetMember is not triggeret. Do i miss something?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SearchResults">
    <Grid Width="294" Margin="6">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,10" Width="40" Height="40">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Banner}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,-10,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SeriesName}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Overview}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The datacontext is set to

```
public ObservableCollection<dynamic> SearchResults {get;set;}
```

and

```
 ICollection col = item.SearchResults;    
 this.DefaultViewModel["Results"] = col;  //this is the datacontext of the gridview
```

Comment: I bet that binding is not correct. Show a XAML binding as well....

Comment: Updated it to include the bindings

Comment: I included a normal property:public string SeriesName { get { return _name; } set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); } } and it is bound correctly.

Comment: I never got back to this and cant remember what solution i found. But the answer below seems okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I am using for kind-of dynamic binding.
The binding syntax just needs to include []:

```
public class DynamicLocalSettings : BindableBase
{
    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey(name))
                return ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[name];
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[name] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you reference the property name in XAML? `Text="{Binding Path=[PropertyName]}"` doesn't work (hangs designer). And putting quotes in doesn't work either (`Text="{Binding Path=["PropertyName"]}"`).

Comment: I am not at my computer so I can't try, but did you try following the example in the question

Comment: Turns out the hanging of the designer was something else. `Path=[PropertyName]` works.