# Binding to DynamicObjects in XAML in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have an `ObservableCollection<dynamic>` class and XAML refuses to bind to the properties on the contained objects.

I know I read somewhere that XAML supports `dynamic` and `DyanmicObject` so I'm mightily confused on why this is not working. Other questions, such as this one, were spectacularly un-helpful:

[Can i bind against a DynamicObject in WinRT / Windows 8 Store Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894952/can-i-bind-against-a-dynamicobject-in-winrt-windows-8-store-apps)

I get this error at runtime (and in the designer at design time when hovering over my `{Binding`s):

`Error: BindingExpression path error: 'DisplayName' property not found on 'PremiseMetro.Light, PremiseMetro, ... BindingExpression: Path='DisplayName' DataItem='PremiseMetro.Light, PremiseMetro, ... target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`

Please help!

Thanks.

A test `ObservableObject` class:

```
class Light : DynamicObject, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
        string name = binder.Name;
        result = null;
        // If the property name is found in a dictionary, 
        // set the result parameter to the property value and return true. 
        // Otherwise, return false. 
        object prop;
        if (_properties.TryGetValue(name, out prop)) {
            result = prop;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // If you try to set a value of a property that is 
    // not defined in the class, this method is called. 
    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) {
        string name = binder.Name;

        _properties[name] = value;
        if (CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
        else
            CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => OnPropertyChanged(name));

        // You can always add a value to a dictionary, 
        // so this method always returns true. 
        return true;
    }

    public object GetMember(string propName) {
        var binder = Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None,
                                      propName, GetType(),
                                      new List<CSharpArgumentInfo> {
                                          CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)
                                      });
        var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(binder);

        return callsite.Target(callsite, this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Sets the value of a property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of property</param>
    /// <param name="val">New value</param>
    /// <param name="fromServer">If true, will not try to update server.</param>
    public void SetMember(String propertyName, object val) {
        var binder = Binder.SetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None,
                                      propertyName, GetType(),
                                      new List<CSharpArgumentInfo> {
                                          CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
                                          CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)
                                      });
        var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(binder);

        callsite.Target(callsite, this, val);
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }            
}
```

A test in my MainViewMOdel constructor:

```
Light light = new Light();
((dynamic) light).DisplayName = "Test Light";
((dynamic) light).Brightness= "27%";
((dynamic) light).PowerState= false;
Lights = new ObservableCollection<dynamic> {
    light
};
```

My test XAML:

```
    <Grid Margin="10" Width="1000" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox x:Name="GDOList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lights}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid Margin="6">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Margin="5" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PowerState}" Margin="5" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Brightness}" Margin="5" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: `DynamicObject` itself doesn't provide a mechanism for member discovery and, as an abstract class, may not know itself whether a particular member exists until it is accessed. This would make it awfully difficult for WinRT to figure out what properties should be represented. Could it be possible that you read that it supports `ExpandoObject` instead?

Comment: My XAML knows the member name. I can't see why the runtime couldn't try dynamic binding if reflection based binding didn't find it. That's what I assumed it would do.

Comment: Found this: http://sdlsdk.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=13690&ProjectName=sdlsdk.  It appears databinding to dynamic objecs is broken (DynamicObject or ExpandoObject) and MS has resolved it as "Wont fix". Blarg.

Comment: @M.Babcock well, `DynamicObject` **DOES** provide a mechanism for member discovery, which is the `GetDynamicMemberNames()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing your ViewModel to:

```
dynamic light = new ExpandoObject();
light.DisplayName = "Test Light";
light.Brightness = "27%";
light.PowerState = false;
var objs = new ObservableCollection<dynamic> { light };
```

and see if that works in your lib correctly?

Comment: Yea, @tim-heuer, `ExpandoObject` works. See my comment above; the fact that `DynamicObject` does not work is a known bug, marked as Wont Fix. Which sucks. I may be able to do what I want with `ExpandoObject`... We'll see.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**: no, binding to an dynamic property on an instance of `DynamicObject` in UWP is not supported.

**However**, there do exist some way to do similar thing, with a `ICustomPropertyProvider`.

Assume your `class` looks something like this:

```
public class SomeClass : DynamicObject, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string _StaticStringProperty;
    public string StaticStringProperty { get => _StaticStringProperty; set => SetField(ref _StaticStringProperty, value); }

    private Dictionary<string, object> _DynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        yield return "DynamicStringProperty";
        yield return "DynamicIntegerProperty";
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = _DynamicProperties.GetValueOrDefault(binder.Name, null);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        _DynamicProperties[binder.Name] = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(binder.Name);
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T target, T value, [CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(target, value))
            return false;
        target = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(caller);
        return true;
    }
}
```

now let it implement `ICustomPropertyProvider`:

```
public class SomeClass : DynamicObject, ICustomPropertyProvider, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    ...
    public Type Type => GetType();
    public string GetStringRepresentation() => ToString();

    public ICustomProperty GetCustomProperty(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            // the caveat is that you have to provide all the static properties, too...
            case nameof(StaticStringProperty):
                return new DynamicCustomProperty<SomeClass, string>()
                {
                    Name = name,
                    Getter = (target) => target.StaticStringProperty,
                    Setter = (target, value) => target.StaticStringProperty = value,
                };
            case "DynamicStringProperty":
                return new DynamicCustomProperty<SomeClass, string>()
                {
                    Name = name,
                    Getter = (target) => target.DynamicStringProperty,
                    Setter = (target, value) => target.DynamicStringProperty = value,
                };
            case "DynamicIntegerProperty":
                return new DynamicCustomProperty<SomeClass, int>()
                {
                    Name = name,
                    Getter = (target) => target.DynamicIntegerProperty,
                    Setter = (target, value) => target.DynamicIntegerProperty = value,
                };
            }
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    ...
}
```

and be able to provide the `DynamicCustomProperty`:

```
public class DynamicCustomProperty<TOwner, TValue> : ICustomProperty
{
    public Func<dynamic, TValue> Getter { get; set; }
    public Action<dynamic, TValue> Setter { get; set; }
    public Func<dynamic, object, TValue> IndexGetter { get; set; }
    public Action<dynamic, object, TValue> IndexSetter { get; set; }

    public object GetValue(object target) => Getter.Invoke(target);
    public void SetValue(object target, object value) => Setter.Invoke(target, (TValue)value);
    public object GetIndexedValue(object target, object index) => IndexGetter.Invoke(target, index);
    public void SetIndexedValue(object target, object value, object index) => IndexSetter.Invoke(target, index, (TValue)value);

    public bool CanRead => Getter != null || IndexGetter != null;
    public bool CanWrite => Setter != null || IndexSetter != null;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type => typeof(TValue);
}
```

finally we're able to bind them in XAML:

```
<TextBox Header="Static String" Text="{Binding StaticStringProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Header="Dynamic String" Text="{Binding DynamicStringProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Header="Dynamic Integer" Text="{Binding DynamicIntegerProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Indeed works 
Finally made it work for UWP https://github.com/xperiandri/Elmish.Uno